# Real analysis of intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that a strictly increasing function f:[a,b]→R which has the intermediate value property is continuous on [a,b]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Pick your favorite point $c \in (a,b)$.

Since $f$ is increasing, both one-sided limits $$\lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \quad \text{and} \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x)$$ exist.

It is evident that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x)$. You should show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) < \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x)$ will violate the intermediate value property. This implies $f$ is continuous at $c$.

The same argument works at the endpoints, just replace the relevant one-sided limits with $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.